# avr How to define a 440Hz sound?

Tags: c, avr, atmega

This code will make a short sound. How can i make a 440hz sound?

edit:
or something like this:? i think i dont want to use fast PWM.

```
#include <avr/io.h>
#include <avr/interrupt.h>

ISR(TIMER1_COMPA_vect) {    
    PORTB = 0;
}

ISR(TIMER1_OVF_vect) {
    PORTB ^= 8;
}

int main(void) {

    DDRB = 8;
    PORTB = 0;
    TCCR1B=(1 << CS10); // Prescaler: 1, Mode: 0
    OCR1A = 9089.91;   // (F_CPU / 2 / 1 / 440) - 1;

    TIMSK1 |= (1 << OCIE1A) | (1 << TOIE1); //Interrupt an
    PCICR = 0x01;
    sei(); // Interrupts global aktivieren

    while(1) {
        };
 }
```

Comment: You will need to tune the delay loops if you want to do it that way. A better method would be to use a hardware timer.

Comment: Are you using a digital output port?

Comment: yes i use a digital output port

Comment: If you are using a digital output port you can generate a PWM signal.Analog waveforms can be generated by averaging the PWM signals over one period using simple lowpass filters. [Here](http://www.atmel.com/Images/Atmel-2542-Using-the-AVR-High-speed-PWM_ApplicationNote_AVR131.pdf) is an application note which may be of help, for generating waveforms with timers

Comment: edit in question

Comment: "*I think I don't want to use PWM*" - I think you want to, you just haven't realised it yet.

Answer (score 1):

You can do it with fast PWM mode.  I've done it before.  The idea is to use the PWM and a low pass filter to create a quantized version of a pure 440Hz sine wave.  This can be done by using a timer to change the duty cycle of a PWM and a low pass filter to isolate the DC component of the PWM.  It's actually not very difficult to implement in software.  The first step is to take a 440Hz sine wave and convert that to an array of unsigned 8 bit values.  I already did this for you, so you would define an array of 8 bit unsigned integers that looks like this:

```
uint8_t wave[] = { 
    0x13, 0x00, 0x00, 0x00, 
    0x80, 0xab, 0xd1, 0xee, 
    0xfd, 0xfe, 0xf0, 0xd4, 
    0xaf, 0x84, 0x58, 0x31, 
    0x13, 0x03, 0x01, 0x0d, 
    0x28, 0x4d, 0x77
};
```

The sine wave was sampled with a frequency of 8000Hz, so in order to recreate the sine wave with the PWM, you would need to set a timer up that fires an interrupt 8000 times a second.  This interrupt is responsible for changing the duty cycle of the PWM to the next index in the sine way array, which would look something like this:

```
ISR(...) {
    OCR1A = wave[index++];
    if (index == wave_array_length) {
        index = 0;
    }
}
```

If you want a real working example of playing audio with a PWM.  I will post a link (if I remember correctly, I used an AT90USB647).